# Resizing hash table - Help me Valgrind-debug my program

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable, valgrind

I'm trying to create a hash table that contains contact numbers and names, when I have too many contacts, I need to resize my hash table. When I do that, I'm having memory leaks + valgrind errors. I've tried many things, can you help me understand or solve the issues?

My hash table structure:

```
struct dir {
    uint32_t len;
    uint32_t contactsNumber;
    struct contact *contactList;
};
```

My `contact` structure:

```
struct contact *contact_create(char *name, char *num) {
    struct contact *init_contact = malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    init_contact->name = name;
    init_contact->num = num;
    init_contact->next = NULL;
    return (init_contact);
}
```

My `resize` function:

```
void dir_resize(struct dir *dir, uint32_t new_size) {
    uint32_t old_size = dir->len;
    struct dir *new_dir = dir_create(new_size);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {
        struct contact *current_contact = dir[i].contactList;
        while (current_contact->next != NULL) {
            dir_insert(new_dir, current_contact->next->name, current_contact->next->num);
            // contact_removeTop(current_contact->next);
            current_contact->next = current_contact->next->next;
        }
        free(current_contact);
    }

    // dir_free(dir);
    // dir = realloc(dir, sizeof(struct dir)*new_size);
    dir->contactsNumber = new_dir->contactsNumber;
    dir->len = new_size;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
        dir[i].contactList = new_dir[i].contactList;
    }
    //dir_free(new_dir);
    //dir_print(dir);
}
```

My `dir_free` function:

```
void dir_free(struct dir *dir) {
    uint32_t size = dir->len;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        contact_free(dir[i].contactList);
    }
    free(dir);
    return;
}
```

My `contact_free` function:

```
void contact_free(struct contact *contact) {
    if (contact == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    while (contact->next != NULL) {
        contact_removeTop(contact);
    }
    free(contact);
}
```

My `dir_create` function:

```
struct dir *dir_create(uint32_t len) {
    struct dir *directory = malloc(sizeof(struct dir) * len);
    //struct dir *directory = malloc(sizeof(struct dir) * len);
    directory->contactsNumber = 0;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        directory[i].contactList = contact_sentinel();
    }

    directory->len = len;
    return (directory);
}
```

Finally, my **resizing.c** test file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <directory.h>

int main(void) {
    struct dir *dir = dir_create(10);
    dir_insert(dir, "A", "06789435351");
    dir_insert(dir, "B", "0678346533");
    dir_print(dir);
    dir_insert(dir, "C", "06723236533");
    dir_print(dir);
    dir_insert(dir, "D", "06723236533");
    dir_print(dir);
    dir_resize(dir, 11);
    dir_print(dir);
    dir_free(dir);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The Valgrind output:

```
==80271== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==80271== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==80271== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==80271== Command: ./tests/resizing-test
==80271== 
------------------------ANNUAIRE-----------------------
Nombre de contacts :2
Taille de l'annuaire :10
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Name -> A, Number -> 06789435351
END.
Name -> B, Number -> 0678346533
END.
--------------------------------------------------------
------------------------ANNUAIRE-----------------------
Nombre de contacts :3
Taille de l'annuaire :10
Name -> C, Number -> 06723236533
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Name -> A, Number -> 06789435351
END.
Name -> B, Number -> 0678346533
END.
--------------------------------------------------------
------------------------ANNUAIRE-----------------------
Nombre de contacts :4
Taille de l'annuaire :10
Name -> C, Number -> 06723236533
END.
Name -> D, Number -> 06723236533
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Name -> A, Number -> 06789435351
END.
Name -> B, Number -> 0678346533
END.
--------------------------------------------------------
==80271== Invalid write of size 8
==80271==    at 0x484B57C: dir_resize (directory.c:162)
==80271==    by 0x10916E: main (resizing.c:16)
==80271==  Address 0x4a5a0e8 is 8 bytes after a block of size 160 alloc'd
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B33B: dir_create (directory.c:24)
==80271==    by 0x1090EE: main (resizing.c:8)
==80271== 
------------------------ANNUAIRE-----------------------
Nombre de contacts :4
Taille de l'annuaire :11
Name -> B, Number -> 0678346533
END.
Name -> C, Number -> 06723236533
END.
Name -> D, Number -> 06723236533
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
==80271== Invalid read of size 8
==80271==    at 0x484B498: dir_print (directory.c:133)
==80271==    by 0x109176: main (resizing.c:17)
==80271==  Address 0x4a5a0e8 is 8 bytes after a block of size 160 alloc'd
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B33B: dir_create (directory.c:24)
==80271==    by 0x1090EE: main (resizing.c:8)
==80271== 
Name -> A, Number -> 06789435351
END.
--------------------------------------------------------
==80271== Invalid read of size 8
==80271==    at 0x484B408: dir_free (directory.c:110)
==80271==    by 0x10917E: main (resizing.c:18)
==80271==  Address 0x4a5a0e8 is 8 bytes after a block of size 160 alloc'd
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B33B: dir_create (directory.c:24)
==80271==    by 0x1090EE: main (resizing.c:8)
==80271== 
==80271== 
==80271== HEAP SUMMARY:
==80271==     in use at exit: 272 bytes in 5 blocks
==80271==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 27 frees, 2,056 bytes allocated
==80271== 
==80271== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 5
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B752: contact_insert (contact.c:37)
==80271==    by 0x484B5D8: dir_insert (directory.c:47)
==80271==    by 0x109107: main (resizing.c:9)
==80271== 
==80271== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 5
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B752: contact_insert (contact.c:37)
==80271==    by 0x484B5D8: dir_insert (directory.c:47)
==80271==    by 0x10911D: main (resizing.c:10)
==80271== 
==80271== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 5
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B752: contact_insert (contact.c:37)
==80271==    by 0x484B5D8: dir_insert (directory.c:47)
==80271==    by 0x10913B: main (resizing.c:12)
==80271== 
==80271== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 5
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B752: contact_insert (contact.c:37)
==80271==    by 0x484B5D8: dir_insert (directory.c:47)
==80271==    by 0x109159: main (resizing.c:14)
==80271== 
==80271== 176 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 5
==80271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==80271==    by 0x484B33B: dir_create (directory.c:24)
==80271==    by 0x484B4F1: dir_resize (directory.c:145)
==80271==    by 0x10916E: main (resizing.c:16)
==80271== 
==80271== LEAK SUMMARY:
==80271==    definitely lost: 272 bytes in 5 blocks
==80271==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==80271==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==80271==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==80271==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==80271== 
==80271== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==80271== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see I have two problems. First, I'm not freeing up the space within the `resize` function, you can look at my commented lines and see that I've already tried freeing up `new_dir` and `dir` but that only resulted in more errors so I gave that up. I don't know how to do it without having a million errors pop up!
Second, when I make my hash table bigger, the memory space allocated to dir no longer corresponds to its new size, which results in the errors. As you can see with my commented lines, I tried reallocating both within and outside the loop, but the error persists. What can I do about it?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**:

This is my `contact_sentinel` function:

```
struct contact *contact_sentinel() {
    struct contact *sentinel = malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    sentinel->name = NULL;
    sentinel->num = NULL;
    sentinel->next = NULL;
    return (sentinel);
}
```

My `dir_insert`:

```
char *dir_insert(struct dir *dir, const char *name, const char *num) {
    uint32_t size = dir->len;
    uint32_t index = hash_modulo(name, size);

    char *number = contact_insert(dir[index].contactList, name, num);

    if (number == NULL) {
        dir->contactsNumber++;
    }

    if (dir->contactsNumber > 0.75 * size) {
        dir_resize(dir, size * 2);
    }

    return number;
}
```

My `contact insert`:

```
char *contact_insert(struct contact *contact, const char *name, const char *num) {
    while (contact->next != NULL) {
        if (contact->name == name) {
            const char *old_num = contact->num;
            contact->num = (char *)num;
            return (char *)old_num;
        }
        contact = contact->next;
    }

    if (contact->name == name) {
        const char *old_num = contact->num;
        contact->num = (char *)num;
        return (char *)old_num;
    }

    contact->next = malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    assert(contact->next != NULL);
    
    contact->next->name = (char *)name;
    contact->next->num = (char *)num;
    contact->next->next = NULL;

    return (NULL);
}
```

Function `hash`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t hash(const char *str) {
    uint32_t hash = 5381;
    uint32_t c;
    
    while ((c = *str++)) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c;
    }

    return hash;
}

uint32_t hash_modulo(const char *name, uint32_t size) {
    return hash(name) % size;
}
```

Function `dir_print`:

```
void dir_print(struct dir *dir) {
    if (dir == NULL) {
        printf("Annuaire vide.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("------------------------ANNUAIRE-----------------------\n");
    printf("Nombre de contacts :%d\n", dir->contactsNumber);
    printf("Taille de l'annuaire :%d\n", dir->len);
    uint32_t len = dir->len;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        contact_print(dir[i].contactList);
    }
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Function `contact_print`:

```
void contact_print(struct contact *contact) {
    contact = contact->next;
    if (contact == NULL) {
        printf("Liste vide.\n");
    }
    while (contact != NULL) {
        printf("Name -> %s, Number -> %s\n", contact->name, contact->num);
        contact = contact->next;
    }
    printf("END.\n");
}
```

Comment: we are missing the def of struct contact, and of a function called contact_sentinel abd dir_insert

Comment: second, is there supposed to be one 'directory' object with  a single  list of contacts. Or are there supposed to be a lot of directory objects each with a separate contact list. You code at the moment cant make up its mind which you want

Comment: dir is a list of directories with chained lists. I added the contact sentinel function. I'll be adding the others.

Comment: still no sign of the contact struct tho

Comment: no dir_print and no hash_modulo - I guessed at contact struct.

Comment: i see many errros here but cannot give a complete answer without the two missing functions.

Comment: I added all the functions you asked for. Contact is defined at the start. You'd be saving my life if you can solve my errors, I'm honestly starting to consider redefining my hash struct with a double pointer contact and rewriting my whole code, thing is: project is due tomorrow lol! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

First - your resize.

You do not need to free the contact lists, you just need to reallocate the dir array.

The new dir structure keeps the old pointers to still valid contact chains

More importantly you did not return the newly creeated directory. All you subsequent operations (in main) still tried to work on the old dir (that you might have freed here). So I made it return the new dir

```
struct dir* dir_resize(struct dir* dir, uint32_t new_size)
{
    uint32_t old_size = dir->len;
    struct dir* new_dir = realloc(dir, new_size * sizeof( * new_dir));
    // initialize the new dir entries
    for (size_t i = old_size; i < new_size; i++) {
        new_dir[i].contactList = contact_sentinel();
    }

    return new_dir;
   }
```

so no leaks now

```
==8769==
==8769== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8769==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==8769==   total heap usage: 18 allocs, 17 frees, 1,720 bytes allocated
==8769==
==8769== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8769==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==8769==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8769==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8769==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8769==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8769== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==8769==
==8769== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==8769== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

other errors

you are only storing text pointers in you contact list. Works at the moment becuase they are literals. But try this

```
struct dir* dir = dir_create(10);
char phone[] = "06789435351";
dir_insert(dir, "A", phone);
strcpy(phone, "0678346533");
dir_insert(dir, "B", phone);
```

output is

(using my print function)

```
=====
(null) (null)
(null) (null)
A 0678346533
(null) (null)
(null) (null)
(null) (null)
(null) (null)
(null) (null)
(null) (null)
B 0678346533
(null) (null)
(null) (null)
```

because you stored the address of 'phone' in the 'contact.num' now both contacts have the same phone number.

you need to do

```
contact->next->num = stdup(num);
```

strdup will malloc space for the string and copy it into the new space for you. You will need to remeber to free the memory at the end.

Also you are very inconsistent with your sentinel. Do you intend that there is always a 'blank' contact at the end. You in fact do not do that. Really you dont need those sentinels at all , just set dir.contactList to NULL when first creating it. At the moment you are allocating an extra memory block for no reason.

---

here

```
while (contact->next != NULL) {
    if (contact->name == name) {
        const char* old_num = contact->num;
        contact->num = (char*)num;
        return(char*)old_num;
    }
    contact = contact->next;
}

if (contact->name == name) {
    const char* old_num = contact->num;
    contact->num = (char*)num;
    return(char*)old_num;
}
```

you are clearly looking to see if that name is already in the list. This

```
 if(contact->name == name)
```

is only working becuase you are stoing the address of literals, so its comparing addresses. It should be

```
   if(strcmp(contact->name, name) == 0)
```

---

OK refixed

put strdup in , added strcmp , fixed resize. No leaks

```
char* contact_insert(struct contact* contact, const char* name, const char* num) {
    
    while (contact->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(contact->name,name)==0) {
            const char* old_num = contact->num;
            contact->num = (char*)num;
            return(char*)old_num;
        }
        contact = contact->next;
    }

    contact->next = malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    assert(contact->next != NULL);

    contact->next->name = strdup(name);
    contact->next->num = strdup(num);
    contact->next->next = NULL;

    return(NULL);

}
```

resize

```
struct dir* dir_resize(struct dir* dir, uint32_t new_size)
{
    uint32_t old_size = dir->len;
    struct dir* new_dir = dir_create(new_size);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {
        struct contact* current_contact = dir[i].contactList;
        while (current_contact->next != NULL) {
            dir_insert(new_dir, current_contact->next->name, current_contact->next->num);
            struct contact* temp = current_contact->next;
            current_contact->next = current_contact->next->next;
            free_contact(temp);

        }

    }
    dir_free(dir);
    
    return new_dir; <<<=== v important
}
```

clean up contacts

```
void free_contact(struct contact* contact) {
    free(contact->name);
    free(contact->num);
    free(contact);
}
void contact_free(struct contact* contact) {

    if (contact == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    while (contact != NULL) {
        struct contact *temp = contact;
        contact = temp->next;
        free_contact(temp);
    }
    
}
```

output

```
------------------------ANNUAIRE-----------------------
Nombre de contacts :4
Taille de l'annuaire :11
Name -> B, Number -> 0678346533
END.
Name -> C, Number -> 06723236533
END.
Name -> D, Number -> 06723236533
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Liste vide.
END.
Name -> A, Number -> 06789435351
END.
--------------------------------------------------------
==14321==
==14321== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14321==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14321==   total heap usage: 48 allocs, 48 frees, 2,166 bytes allocated
==14321==
==14321== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14321==
==14321== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==14321== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Thank for your input!
I'm not exactly sure your version of dir_resize does what it's supposed to though. When I make the table bigger, the hash are changing since they depend on the size, meaning contacts go into different indexes. I'm not merely copying dir into new_dir and adding new contacts, but I'm also reordering it.

Comment: @Lamett aha - good point, I hacked your hash function. Need to revisit the resize

Comment: @Lamett OK now i find more errors. See edit

Comment: @Lamett that sentinel is very odd. You always have a blank entry at the start of the list, I assumed it was always the last one (so you know where the end is) not no. Its always there, unused at the start of the contactList, which is why you have a `conatc=contact->next` at the start of print_contact. I wrote my own printf before you posted it and was surpised by the output. I strongly suggest getting rid of it, just have dir->contactList = NULL to signal empty chain.

Comment: @Lamett its  why you have all this `next->next` stuff, you are always having to skip the first element of the contcats array

Comment: @Lamett redone, now doing the correct rehash